# How to start evaluating a cold IObservable

Tags: c#, system.reactive, observable

I thought, that cold IObservables, like the one returned from `Observable.Create` are evaluated whenever a subscription to them is made. I made a subscription. The IObservable did not evaluate.

```
class Program
{
    static IObservable<int> HotSource()
    {
        return Observable.Generate<int, int>(0, x => x <= 100, x => x + 1, x => x);
    }
    static IObservable<int> ColdSource()
    {
        return Observable.Create<int>(subscriber => () =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 100; ++i)
            {
                subscriber.OnNext(i);
            }
        });
    }
    static void Process(IObservable<int> numbers)
    {
        numbers
            .Take(15)
            .Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hot");
        Process(HotSource());
        Console.WriteLine("Cold");
        Process(ColdSource());
        Console.WriteLine("End");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "did not evaluate"? What did you see? Does anything change if you remove the `Take` call? (Thanks for the complete sample though - will run it when I can.)

Comment: I see printed numbers from `HotSource` (when I remove call to `HotSource`, it disappears). When I put a breakpoint to action inside `ColdSource` it doesn't trigger. `Take` just reduces amount of numbers from `HotSource`, it's not really needed.

Comment: Your `HotSource()` is actually returning a cold `IObservable` as the values will only be generated when a subscription is made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Create method is off. This will work:

```
    static IObservable<int> ColdSource()
    {
        return Observable.Create<int>(subscriber =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 100; ++i)
            {
                subscriber.OnNext(i);
            }
            subscriber.OnCompleted();
            return Disposable.Empty;
        });
    }
```

The way you had it written, you were returning an `Action` which happens upon un-subscription. You want the code to happen upon subscription.

Incidentally, your 'Hot' observable isn't very hot. I don't know if that makes a difference to you. You can see that in this code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hot 1");
        var hotSource = HotSource();
        Process(hotSource);
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
        Console.WriteLine("Hot 2");
        Process(hotSource);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

If `hotSource` were truly hot, each number would only print once, or they would print simultaneously (1, 1, 2, 2, etc..).

Comment: If you are returning an `IDisposable` from create, be sure to use `subscriber.OnCompleted()`, the other option is to not return an `IDisposable` and that overload of `Create` will call `OnCompleted()` automatically.

Comment: Added onCompleted. Thanks.

Comment: Now added onCompleted. :) Change didn't stick first time.